# How should I store beansprouts?

Tags: storage-method, beans

Bean sprouts are a common ingredient in stir-fry recipes, but they don't seem to last very long in my fridge.

How can I keep bean sprouts fresh for the maximum amount of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like ehow has the [best reference guide](http://www.ehow.com/how_6178837_preserve-bean-sprouts.html) thus far to storing bean sprouts

After purchasing Bean Sprouts should be stored and washed after purchasing in growing. The article indicates that the best methods for storage are the following:

- Wash them after you purchase them.

> Wash bean sprouts after purchasing or growing. Wash them in cold water to remove seed 
>   coats, roots and other residue that may be present. If you are using
>   them within a day, store them in the refrigerator at 40 to 45 degrees.
>   Place the sprouts in a plastic bag with a wet paper towel to keep them
>   moist.

- Store in icy water and change the water few times a day

> You can also store sprouts in a bucket of icy water and change the
>   water a few times a day. Depending on how long the sprouts were in
>   transit or on the store shelf, they should last longer than when
>   stored in a plastic bag.

- Freeze them

> Freeze sprouts for the longest storage. Wash sprouts as described in
>   Step One. Then heat one layer at a time in steam for three minutes.
>   Cool right away in icy water and drain. Put the sprouts into plastic
>   containers and seal.

It also mentions in the [article](http://www.ehow.com/how_6178837_preserve-bean-sprouts.html) to just grow them to provide the best freshness.

Apparently the shelf life of beansprouts should only be stored up to [3 days](http://www.foodreference.com/html/art-sprouts-types-tips.html)

Source: http://www.ehow.com/how_6178837_preserve-bean-sprouts.html#ixzz1pAEZ12Jp

Comment: Note: ehow is paid for content, though it is often screen scraped, or just plain wrong

Comment: It shouldn't discredit the answers i've provided. I've reviewed them with other sources.

Answer (score 1):

I've been keeping them in a jar in the crisper section of the refrigerator, and they seem to be still fairly crunchy going on two weeks. 
I found a jar of them last week that'd I'd forgotten from the previous week and they were in much better shape than the ones bought nine days later but for which I didn't have an available jar.

I don't rinse mine until right before I use them; most of my vegetables seem to keep longer that way (presumably because they'd be nearly impossible to dry thoroughly).

Edited to clarify: I always cover everything thoroughly, so the newer sprouts were wrapped in wax paper, then aluminum foil.

Answer (score 0):

My sister got these green veggie storage bags in Walmart. They make everything last longer. Not sure what they are called about 8x16” in size. Great for lettuce. Havent tried with bean sprouts yet but, great for fruit and veggies.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found after trying many other ways, was to just put them in a sealed plastic container immediately after you bring them home from the supermarket, fill it with water and store them in a fridge. They will last for weeks.