# Sprouted Legumes? How long do they keep?

Tags: storage-lifetime

I purchased sprouted lentils over four weeks ago.  They are fresh, not dehydrated.  I've kept them refrigerated.  They look and smell fine.  Are they still good to use after all this time, or must I discard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I store beansprouts?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22268/how-should-i-store-beansprouts)

Comment: @bob1 I beg to differ, sprouted lentils are very different from bean sprouts...

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza - we must agree to disagree then. The safety considerations are the same for both types.